# Custom Product Code - Computer Vision - Python

Tags: python, computer-vision

For a project I require to read a product code (similar to a QR code), from an webcam. However unlike a QR code - which has many python libraries that make the scanning very easy - I need to make a custom product code - which means I need a custom library. The code design is very simple - one shape corresponds to '1' and another shape corresponds to '0'.

Does anyone know how I would program the reader in python? What kind of algorithm should I be looking into? In terms of programming proficiency I would say I'm a beginner (so please try and refrain from using complicated terms).

Comment: Hi, it would to useful, if you post some of your code here. Where did you get so far? Have you tried to code it? Otherwise, there will be a lot of angry users voting you down, because it looks like you are just asking for the code.

Comment: That's the thing I don't know where to start. What should I be looking for? E.g. Should I be researching haar cascades? Etc.

Comment: Why not program an encoding first? Make a module that encodes 1 and 0 into the two different shapes, and then another one that decodes them. Or do you have to have a visual code physically on a paper?

Comment: Yes they will be physically printed on paper (like a QR code.)

Comment: For me I'm finding it hard to understand how Python will distinguish the code from the rest of the image.

Comment: For example if I use edge detection, how would I combine that and thresholding? (Just an example.)

Answer (score 0):

First you can design a simple encoding scheme and program it using opencv. OpenCV has methods to draw basic shapes on images.

You can start by reading [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/the-ultimate-barcode-detection-guide.pdf) on standard barcode detection. If your code is too complex to be detected using this method, you can train a Haar classifier.

Depending on rthe design of your code, hough line transform, Hough circle transform, homography etc. can be used to read back the code after detection.

I once wrote an encoder and decoder using leaf-like patterns. You can contact me at chamin.yubi@icloud.com if you want the code for that (the code is rusty and I am slow to reply, though).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Zbar (zbar.sourceforge.net), is the library I'm currently using to read QR codes. On the 'about' page it says that it looks at the image as an array, reads each line as a line from a laser bar code scanner, and applies 'simple 1D signal proccessing'. Could I use this method for detecting my custom code? What sorts of algrothims and '1D signal proccesing' should I use?

Comment: This method can be theoretically applied to any custom code that uses only two colors (one for the pattern and another for the background). Since the library can read QR codes, that means it has better functionality than a laser barcode scanner.
For decoding a 1D barcode from a 1D scanner signal, you need algorithms like scaling (cater to diagonal scans), correlation (decoding), and filtering (noise reduction while not blurring the barcode pattern too much).

Comment: Would this be harder than using, lets say a Haar classifie, or using opencv image manipulation methods?

Comment: A Haar classifier will be good for barcode localization; that is to find the exact location and size of the barcode if it is not in the center of the image, and/or can appear in different sizes. But for actually decoding the code, training a Haar classifier for each possible code is not practical.
If your code is very different from standard barcodes (like patterns of tree branches, for example), decoding using OpenCV will be faster. Otherwise, I recommend using this library.